# Copy paste option is disabled in ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

I have installed ubuntu 20.10 installation was successful but I am not able to copy paste my files from one drive to another. When I select copy by clicking right on file but not able to paste in targeted destination.paste option is disabled in targeted drive
Am trying to copy from download folder to drive B

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have write permissions on the destination?

Comment: @Matigo I was trying to set full read and write permsion but was getting error then I searched alot and found a reason. I had installed ubuntu on that drive before then I did not uninstall ubuntu and attached that drive in my laptop. So I need to uninstall ubuntu from that drive by formatting then may be I will be able to copy paste data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by myself. My paste option  was disabled because I had installed ubuntu on this drive with virtual machine. I followed these steps.
1- I copied data from that drive to other
2- then I formatted that drive

Now am able to copy paste in that drive.thanks to myself

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to set permission or re-mount the drive with read/write permissions, you should try cp command from terminal it will give you more clear reasons

usage:
cp current_location_of_file new_location_of_file
cp /home/juni/myFile /home/junaid/

and i don't think this could be your reinstallation issue,

Comment: as I told you I was not able to change permission from read only to create and delete files. Then I followed my  steps which I share in answer then it's working fine